# Hide product description in the shop page Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to disable products short description on woocommerce shop page. I cannot use CSS because I use short description on other pages.
I might need to use some php but I don't know witch code to use.
Can someone help me with this? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shop page is different than the product page so it should be possible to do with CSS with targeting.

Example:

```
.post-type-archive.woocommerce{

}
```

This is part of the class data that *should* be in your top header area (html or body element).

Through PHP that would be `is_shop()` (the main shop page).